# Why eq doesn't exist for mongo-java-driver?

Tags: java, mongodb-query, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I've found in [mongodb tutorial for java](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) about how to query from mongo collection but the `eq` which they use doesn't work for me! Do you know how to filter documents from a collection with mongo and java?

This is my try:

```
package Database;

import org.bson.Document;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.client.FindIterable;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // insert something to mongo:
        final String URI = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
        final String DB = "StackOverflowQuestion";
        final String COLLECTION = "eqDoesntExcist";

        MongoClientURI connection = new MongoClientURI(URI);
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(connection);
        MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase(DB);
        MongoCollection<Document> collection =  database.getCollection(COLLECTION);

        Document doc = new Document("name", "Troy").append("height", 185);
        collection.insertOne(doc);

        doc = new Document("name", "Ann").append("height", 175);
        collection.insertOne(doc);

        // read something from mongo
        FindIterable<Document> findIt = collection.find(eq("name", "Troy"));
        // ERROR!!! the method eq(String, String) is undefined!

        mongo.close();

    }

}
```

I want something like:

```
SELECT * from eqDoesntExcist WHERE name = "Troy"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use an `eq` [`Filter`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html#eq-java.lang.String-TItem-) there as:

```
 Bson bsonFilter = Filters.eq("name", "Troy");
 FindIterable<Document> findIt = collection.find(bsonFilter);
```

or else to make it look the way doc suggests include a static import for the method call `Filters.eq`

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;
```

and further use the same piece of code as yours :

```
FindIterable<Document> findIt = collection.find(eq("name", "Troy")); // static import is the key to such syntax
```

Comment: So why their tutorial is mistaken?

Comment: @WW tutorial is not mistaken, have updated the answer. To use such format, you need to include a static import of the method in use. In your case `Filters.eq`.

Comment: **The method find(DBObject) in the type DBCollection is not applicable for the arguments (Bson)** . I keep on getting this when i am trying to execute the last statement

Answer (score -1):

you can not do this:

```
collection.find(eq("name", "Troy"));
```

because the compiler will expect in your class `StackOverflow` a method with the name `eq` and this is not what you need..

what you are looking for is defined in the [Filter class](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/?com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html)

```
public static <TItem> Bson eq(String fieldName, Item value)
```

so it may be

```
collection.find(Filters.eq("name", "Troy"));
```

Comment: So why their tutorial is mistaken?

Comment: The are not.... the method is static and maybe they are importing that class statically....

Comment: What is in https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/getting-started/quick-start/ is certainly wrong for eq filter usage, based on the above note.